# How can I bind to the select2 change event and get the selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, sonata-admin

I have a select element which is decorated by Select2 via the SonataAdminBundle.

I am trying to listen to the change event. The ID of my select tag is "categorySelector".

This does not work:

```
var test = $('#categorySelector');

$(test).change(function() {

    var theSelection = $(test).select2("val");
    //$('#selectedID').text(theID);
   console.log(theSelection);
});
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work for you...

```
$('#categorySelector').on("change", function(e) {
    var theSelection = e.val();
    console.log(theSelection);
});
```

Comment: In my case the val was not a function and I had to do a `var selectedValue = e.val;`

Answer (score 1):

All public events are relayed using the jQuery event system, and they are triggered on the  element that Select2 is attached to. You can attach to them using the .on method provided by jQuery:

```
$('#categorySelector').on('select2:select', function (e) {
  // Do something
});
```

When select2:select is triggered, data from the selection can be accessed via the params.data

In param.data you received object like:

```
{selected: true, disabled: false, text: "India", id: "101", title: "", …}
```

then you can simple apply text or id property.

```
$('#categorySelector').on('select2:select', function (e) {
    var theSelection = e.params.data.id;
    console.log(theSelection );
});
```